# Trouble installing percona 5.6 on Google compute engine debian

Tags: mysql, percona, percona-server

I've been trying to install percona server on a fresh Google compute engine instance.

I haven't installed mysql server previously. 
I followed the instructions from [here](http://www.unixmen.com/install-percona-server-5-6-phpmyadmin-debian-7-wheezy/).

I get this when I use:

```
apt-get install percona-server-server-5.6 percona-server-client-5.6


Setting up percona-server-common-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
Setting up percona-server-client-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
Setting up percona-server-server-5.6 (5.6.15-rel63.0-519.wheezy) ...
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL (Percona Server): mysqld.
2014-01-22 04:54:28 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated.     Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2014-01-22 04:54:28 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.15-    rel63.0 started; log sequence number 1625987
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] RSA private key file not found:     /var/lib/mysql//private_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] RSA public key file not found: /var/lib/mysql//public_key.pem. Some authentication plugins will not work.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] Binlog end
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2014-01-22 04:54:29 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2014-01-22 04:54:30 21278 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625997


 * Percona Server is distributed with several useful UDF (User Defined Function) from Percona Toolkit.
 * Run the following commands to create these functions:

    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv1a_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv1a_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION fnv_64 RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libfnv_udf.so'"
    mysql -e "CREATE FUNCTION murmur_hash RETURNS INTEGER SONAME 'libmurmur_udf.so'"

 * See http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-server/5.5/management/udf_percona_toolkit.html for more details


[FAIL] Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
```

What am I doing wrong?

When I type `/etc/init.d/mysql start`
I get

```
[....] Starting MySQL (Percona Server) database server: mysqld/etc/init.d/mysql: fork: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 48: /usr/bin/tail: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 47: /bin/grep: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 46: /usr/bin/tr: Cannot allocate memory
/etc/init.d/mysql: line 45: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Cannot allocate memory
/lib/lsb/init-functions: fork: Cannot allocate memory
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the exact same problem on an AWS t1.micro that has about .6GB of memory. It would go through the entire setup process then fail on initializing mysqld. As it turns out, that instance did not have enough memory to get percona server 5.6 going. I brought up a faster instance running 3.75GB of memory and it started without issue.

If I were to speculate, I would guess you are on the f1-micro instance which is why you are getting the "Cannot allocate memory" errors. Try the g1-small instance and see if that is enough to get mysql running.

**Update:**
I was/am using Percona's default configuration and I was able to successfully install on a Digital Ocean droplet with 1GB of memory. So, it seems as though the magic number of needed memory is between .6GB and 1GB.

Comment: Agree with your diagnosis.  Only comment I have is that it is possible to change defaults to use less memory: http://www.tocker.ca/2014/03/10/configuring-mysql-to-use-minimal-memory.html - but upgrading the instance is a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. Yes i got a similar answer on StackOverflow. I got a bigger instance and it worked. Percona server seems to hog atleast 400mb+ memory and that could be the reason it did not work on the smaller instance. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21274573/installing-percona-5-6-on-google-compute-engine-debian